# Laminas abstract factories calling order

Tags: php, zend-framework, laminas

I have list of my own abstract factories in `module.config.php` of my module:

```
'service_manager' => [
    'abstract_factories' => [
        \Base\Logic\Factory\AbstractLogicFactory::class,
        \Base\Form\AbstractFormFactory::class,
        Command\Factory\AbstractCommandFactory::class,
    ],
],
```

But before one of them is fired `Laminas\Di\Container\AutowireFactory` creates an empty class of an object which should be created via one of the mentioned factories in configuration.

Can I change order of firing abstract factories while using Service Manager? Or maybe even turn off `AutowireFactory`.